# Is there any way to generate 50 functions from the same formula in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I would like to generate 50 functions derived by: xk'=-x_{k-1}*x_{k-2}-x_{k} ,where k=1,2,..50. Is there any 'clever' way to do it without writing them manually. For example How can I generate

x5'=-x_{4}*x_{3}-x{5} 
.... 
x30'=-x_{29}*x_{28}-x{30}

for all k from 1 to 50 but I want x1,...,x50 to be symbols-variables, thus, later on I can invoke them like this x34(15)=..

Thanks for the help

Comment: See: [Anonymous Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

Comment: yes, I know this and this is the answer of the second part of my question. My problem is how to produce 50 functions with 50 variables.

Comment: You don't need to produce 50 functions, you produce 1 function with 2 inputs.

Comment: yes but I want these two inputs to be variables, not numbers.

Comment: How does that preclude the use of an anonymous function?

Comment: I have xk'=-x_{k-1}*x_{k-2}-x_{k}

How can I generate x5'=-x_{4}*x_{3}-x{5}
                                 ....                   
                                x30'=-x_{29}*x_{28}-x{30}

for all k from 1 to 50

but I want x1,...,x50 to be symbols, thus, later on I can invoke them as x20(i) for example.

Comment: @vanboeren You can do this with a single anonymous function (that accepts inputs `k` and `x`). Better yet make it a real function so it's legible.

Answer (score 0):

As Suever suggests, accomplish with an anonymous function which takes 2 inputs not 1!

```
xkFunc = @(x,k) - x{k} * x{k-1} - x{k}
```

You haven't stated what the inputs are, but from your notation I'm assuming `x` is a cell and `k` is an integer for indexing. In that case, this will work. If `x` is a vector/matrix (not cell) then use regular brackets instead

```
xkFunc = @(x,k) - x(k) * x(k-1) - x(k)
```

You stated that you want to be able to call `x5`, `x6`, ... instead you would call
`xkFunc(x,5)` for example.

MATLAB replaces the bracketed variables after the `@` with subsequent inputs, anywhere in the formula when called.